# How can I parse a mongo string into object in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In java there are ways to do so

http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/

looking for the same in nodejs/frontend code. 
is there any way?

currently using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/loose-json

but no support for ObjectId for example..

Answer (score 0):

Since NodeJS is javascript, [all you need to do is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object):

```
JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: That will not work in the example given in : http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-convert-json-data-to-dbobject/ - the link I pasted in the question deliberately.. 
As mongo queries are not necessarily valid JSON objects.